# Passing multiple dates from view to controller to store in Database

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that I had to change to add and save multiple start and end dates. I have a jQuery/jQuery-UI(datetimepicker) call that will dynamically create more input fields based on what the user wants to enter (code given below). I don't really now how to pass all the dates to the controller because the viewModel is looking for just one `StartDate` and `EndDate`. All the Id's are incremented and the class name is auto generated to `hasDatePicker` from the Jquery-UI plugin. I'm thinking that I can someway changing the ViewModel type into  List<> might help in some sort of way but really I don't know best practices and what other options are out there.

Let me know what other information is needed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="field_wrapper2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="DisplayFieldName">
                # of start and end dates to create
            </td>
            <td class="DisplayFieldData" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;">
                <input type="text" name="numOfDates" id="numOfDates" value="0" />
                <button class="numOfDatesBtn" id="numOfDatesBtn" type="button">Add Dates</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
      $(function() {
    function makenewDateTimePicker(i, aObj) {
      var startRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(aObj);
      var startLabel = $("<td>").html("<label for='start-date-" + i + "'>Start:</label>").appendTo(startRow);
      var startInput = $("<td>").html("<input type='text' id='start-date-" + i + "' />").appendTo(startRow);        

      var endRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(aObj);
      var endLabel = $("<td>").html("<label for='end-date-" + i + "'>End:</label>").appendTo(startRow);
      var endInput = $("<td>").html("<input type='text' id='end-date-" + i + "' />").appendTo(startRow);          
    }

    $("#numOfDatesBtn").click(function() {
      var num = parseInt($("#numOfDates").val());
      var c = $("input[id^='start-date']").length;
      c++;
      for (c; c <= num; c++) {
        makenewDateTimePicker(c, $(".field_wrapper2"));
      }
    });
  });
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class DatePeriodViewModel
{
  public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }      
  public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateAuction(DatePeriodViewModel viewModel) {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the cleanest solution but you can try capturing the submit event on the browser and then appending an array of dates to the form, which you can then access on the controller.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    var dates = // create an array of the dates, try using $(".hasDatePicker").each(...)
    $(this).append(dates); //append to the form
    return true; //return true to proceed with the submitting chain
});
```